# TSQL - Partial Matching using LIKE for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to seek your advice whether any function in SQL server that allow me to perform partial matching for a list of values ?

The entire string that need to be matched will be passed in via store procedure.

I am trying to find other alternative before writing my own function to split the string by comma and then union all the results before return the data to the program.

For example, I would pass in the following string into my TSQL

> apple,orange,pear

in my `WHERE` clause it should match

```
select * from store where fruits like 'apple%'
select * from store where fruits like 'orange%'
select * from store where fruits like 'pear%'
```

Can I achieve the above results in a single SQL statement rather than writing function to break each string ?

> Data in my Table

```
apple red
apple green
orange sweet
orange sour
pear big
pear small
```

So, when I passed in the string "apple,pear" , I need to return

```
apple red
apple green
pear big
pear small
```

Comment: What does `fruits` looks like?  Don't say comma-separated values.  That is a very, very poor design for a relational database.

Comment: I am just using a simple table for illustration.

Comment: You have a fundamental problem with your data structure.  You should not be storing lists of things as strings.  Instead, you should be using a junction table.

Comment: @user3015739 is asking for a general solution to match a string consisting of a comma-separated list of arbitrary words. Most posters here missed that.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a temp table as

```
'CREATE TABLE #Pattern (
      SearchItems VARCHAR(20)
    );'
```

Side note: Make sure you check if the temp table exists to avoid errors.
Now you can insert your search words to the temp table as

```
'INSERT 
    INTO #Pattern 
    VALUES 
        ('% APPLE %'),
        ('% ORANGE %'),
        ('% BANANA %');'
```

Now using this temp table, Search your table using a INNER JOIN
like

```
'SELECT *
 FROM Store
 INNER JOIN #Pattern
    ON Store.Fruits LIKE SearchItems
'
```

As a note, Temp Tables are something I try to avoid mostly, but here it comes handy, and the case I was using this solution was not demanding on performance. Rather it made it easier to keep the ever growing searchItems maintained.

Hope this works for others too.

Answer (score 7):

It could be as simple as:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  store
WHERE
  fruits LIKE 'apple%'
  OR fruits LIKE 'orange%'
  OR fruits LIKE 'pear%'
```

Comment: The string will be passed in from a store procedure and I need to return the data set using pattern matching. I have no problem writing a function to split the string and then union the results. Just try to explore what other options I have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but performance will not be great

```
declare @parm varchar(200)
set @parm = ','+'apple,orange,pear'+','

select * from store where charindex(fruit,@parm) > 0
```

Comment: It didn't work because you can't have apple,orange in the same data. I am just using pattern matching to find all apple red, apple green, orange big, orange small.

Comment: Sorry, type - I reversed parameters.    Try the changed version

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here on how to use XML to split.

I'll just insert the values into a table and then query it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Full-Text Searching):

```
SELECT  *
FROM store
WHERE CONTAINS(fruits , '"apple*" OR "orange*" OR "pear*"')
```

And here is the help to implement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: ***`"Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view xxx.yyy' because it is not full-text indexed."`***

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to do it in SQL, but it is quite complicated. Assuming you can live with matching a string of up to, say, three fruit names, you proceed in the following manner.

We assume that `@fruits` is the `varchar` variable containing the list of fruits, to which we append more comma delimiters (in case it contains less than three fruit names):

```
declare @fruits varchar(80);
set @fruits = <list of fruits passed in> + ',_,_,_,';
```

The following equations are not SQL, but the math behind the substring operations we will need for the `like` expressions:

```
NOTE: NOT SQL

First fruit word:
p1 = charindex(',', @fruits)            << position of ',' delimiter
v1 = substring(@fruits, 0, p1-1) + '%'  << fruit word we seek
r1 = substring(@fruits, p1+1)           << remainder of string

Second fruit word:    
p2 = charindex(',', r1)
v2 = substring(r1, 0, p2-1) + '%'
r2 = substring(r1, p2+1)

Third fruit word:
p3 = charindex(',', r2)
v3 = substring(r2, 0, p3-1) + '%'
r3 = substring(r2, p3+1)

...and so on...
```

Now we substitute the first values of `p1`, `v1`, and `r1` into the second set of equations for `p2`, `v2`, and `r2`. And likewise, we substitute those second set of values into the third set, and so on. We end up with these monstrosities for `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`:

```
v1 = substring(@fruits, 0, charindex(',', @fruits)-1) + '%'
v2 = substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), 0, charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))-1) + '%'
v3 = substring(substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))+1), 0, charindex(',', substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))+1))-1) + '%'
```

These are the first three `LIKE` values we need to look for:

```
select * from fruits
where fruit like <v1>
   or fruit like <v2>
   or fruit like <v3>
```

Fully expanded, the query is:

```
select * from fruits
where fruit like substring(@fruits, 0, charindex(',', @fruits)-1) + '%'
   or fruit like substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), 0, charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))-1) + '%'
   or fruit like substring(substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))+1), 0, charindex(',', substring(substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1), charindex(',', substring(@fruits, charindex(',', @fruits)+1))+1))-1) + '%'
```

We can do more work to extract the 4th word, 5th word, 6th word, and so on as far as we like. But each further `vN` value gets far more complicated than the previous.

*Note: I have not tried this solution, I have only proved it mathematically.*